# Updating CSV Column Values Using UA-Parser Library

Tags: php, csv

I'm using the [ua-parser library](https://github.com/ua-parser/) to identify the device family for a number of user agent strings in a spreadsheet column. The problem I'm running into is that it doesn't seem like my function is really running. The value output for detectAgent($data[2]) is not always accurate.

Here's a code sample. I feel like I must be missing something related to the limitations of creating objects over and over again.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use UAParser\Parser;

function detectAgent($ua) {
    $parser = Parser::create();
    $result = $parser->parse($ua);
    return $result->os->family;
}

$input_file = "input.csv";
$output_file = "output.csv";

if (($handle1 = fopen($input_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    if (($handle2 = fopen($output_file, "w")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle1, 5000000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
           // Alter your data
            #print $data . "<br />";
           $data[2] = detectAgent($data[2]); //identify browser family

           // Write back to CSV format
           fputcsv($handle2, $data);
        }
        fclose($handle2);
    }
    fclose($handle1);
}
?>
```

Comment: I wonder if I should be using a method to destroy $parser at the end of the detectAgent function.

Answer (score 0):

This was a silly mistake. I was writing to the wrong column in `$data[2] = detectAgent($data[2]);`.

If anyone else runs into the same problem, the code is working now and I've posted an example [here](https://github.com/juliakm/User-Agent-CSV-Parse).